# How to activate both the Anaconda environment and the Typescript watcher?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

```json
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
        "-ExecutionPolicy", "ByPass", "-NoExit", "-Command", "& 'C:/Users/Marko/anaconda3/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate 'C:/Users/Marko/anaconda3'"
    ]
```

I put in the above in my VS Code `settings.json` file. This causes the Powershell to be started as if I had passed in `-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -Command "& 'C:\Users\Marko\anaconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate 'C:\Users\Marko\anaconda3' "` as arguments to it. This works fine enough on its own, but I am working on a VS Code extension in Typescript, and when I run it, it tries starting the Typescript watcher and I get the following error.

```
> Executing task: & 'c:\Users\Marko\Source\Repos\The Spiral Language\VS Code Plugin\node_modules\.bin\tsc.cmd' -p 'c:\Users\Marko\Source\Repos\The Spiral Language\VS Code Plugin\tsconfig.json' --watch <

At line:1 char:113
+ ... k.ps1' ; conda activate 'C:/Users/Marko/anaconda3' -Command & 'c:\Use ...
+                                                                 ~
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed
```

This works fine when PS is started without the arguments to activate Anaconda. Would it be possible to adjust my settings so that both Anaconda and the TS watcher can be started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67702711/4364027). Just running `conda init` will set things up set the Anaconda env gets initialized on Powershell's startup.