# How to make the Python debug task use the default Powershell profile?

Tags: python, powershell, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run a Python file in debug mode, and I get an error because the Powershell integrated terminal it starts is bare. To get it to work, I want it to use the following profile which initializes the Anaconda env first.

```
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "PowerShell -conda": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "args": ["-ExecutionPolicy", "ByPass", "-NoExit", "-Command", "& 'C:/Users/Marko/anaconda3/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate 'C:/Users/Marko/anaconda3'"]
            }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell -conda"
```

What should I do to make that happen?

Comment: For now, a workaround is to run `C:/Users/Marko/anaconda3/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1` and then `conda activate 'C:/Users/Marko/anaconda3'` by hand in the debug terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to init conda first.

Run `conda init` command in any terminal.

It will create a **profile.ps1** file under the folder of **C:\Users{UserName}\Documents\WindowsPowerShell**.

After that, if you open the PowerShell, conda will work. It equals to **C:/Users/Marko/anaconda3/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1**

Comment: After running `conda init` everything works automatically and I do not need the profile setting in my original post. I don't even need to activate the Python env or add stuff to PATH. The solution is as good as I could imagine it to be.

Answer (score 0):

If you want conda environment is activated every time opening an new integrated Terminal, after selecting conda environment as interpreter, what you need to do is pressing **Ctrl+Shift+`** to open a Terminal

1. run `conda activate <envname>`
2. In Settings.json, set `"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true`

Then no matter run or debug code, Terminal is always activated automatically:

[image]

Comment: When I turn on that option what happens is that `conda activate base` gets run in the terminal. The problem is that it does not run the `C:/Users/Marko/anaconda3/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1` and I get an error that it cannot find `conda`. That is why I keep that option turned off and have my own terminal profile.

Comment: Seems you didn't add Anaconda to PATH, so there's error showing `can't find conda`. Try to add `\installation path\Anaconda` and `\installation path\Anaconda\Scripts` to PATH.